# LookupError: No installed app with label '—'

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy my django project by following [this link](https://medium.com/djangotube/deploy-django-using-postgres-nginx-in-digital-ocean-ubuntu-droplet-d4e1de81254f)

however I have done everything that blog specified and im getting error in its last step. While restarting `supervisorctl`

```
(venv) ubuntu@ip-:~/UNIQUETRADE$ sudo supervisorctl restart django-demo
django-demo: stopped
django-demo: ERROR (spawn error)
```

While running `manage.py runserver` I'm not getting any error. But when running `python manage.py check — deploy` I'm getting below error.

```
(venv) ubuntu@ip-:~/UNIQUETRADE$ python manage.py check — deploy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/UNIQUETRADE/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 158, in get_app_config
    return self.app_configs[app_label]
KeyError: '—'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/UNIQUETRADE/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ubuntu/UNIQUETRADE/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/UNIQUETRADE/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ubuntu/UNIQUETRADE/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/UNIQUETRADE/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/UNIQUETRADE/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/UNIQUETRADE/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/check.py", line 56, in handle
    app_configs = [apps.get_app_config(app_label) for app_label in app_labels]
  File "/home/ubuntu/UNIQUETRADE/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/check.py", line 56, in <listcomp>
    app_configs = [apps.get_app_config(app_label) for app_label in app_labels]
  File "/home/ubuntu/UNIQUETRADE/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 165, in get_app_config
    raise LookupError(message)
LookupError: No installed app with label '—'.
```

Here is my error log recorded from `/var/log/gunicorn_supervisor.log`:

```
[2023-03-13 17:40:58 +0000] [7464] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2023-03-13 17:40:58 +0000] [7464] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (7464)
[2023-03-13 17:40:58 +0000] [7464] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-03-13 17:40:58 +0000] [7465] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7465
[2023-03-13 17:40:58 +0000] [7465] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/UNIQUETRADE/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/UNIQUETRADE/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/UNIQUETRADE/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/UNIQUETRADE/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/UNIQUETRADE/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/UNIQUETRADE/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/ubuntu/UNIQUETRADE/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '—'
[2023-03-13 17:40:58 +0000] [7465] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7465)
[2023-03-13 17:40:58 +0000] [7464] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2023-03-13 17:40:58 +0000] [7464] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Edit: heres my installed app-

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "broker_auth",
    "investor",
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
]
```

Comment: Show your `INSTALLED_APPS` from settings.py

Comment: @BartoszStasiak I have updated my installed app. This project is working if i simply python manage.py runserver. Only during deployment im getting this error